# How can I implement partial reduce in scala?

Tags: scala

Here is the scene: only reduce elements under some specified circumstances.

Eg. `val sen = List("Jone", "had", "a", "great", "time", ".")`, if element ends up with "e", so concatenate it with the next element.  For `sen`, the result could be `("Jone had", "a", "great", "time .")`.

Is there any elegant way to achieve these rather than a loop?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you ask. Why in your example `"great"` is not concatenated with `"time"` if it contains `e` and they are consecutive?

Comment: Sorry, should be ends up with, already updated.

Comment: And something like `val x = List("ae", "be", "ce")` to what would be reduced from your viewpoint?

Comment: to a List contains one element `("ae be ce")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `foldLeft` as in:

```
val result = sen.foldLeft(List[String]()) {
    (rs, s) => 
      if (rs.nonEmpty && rs.head.endsWith("e")) 
        (rs.head + " " + s) :: rs.tail 
      else 
        s :: rs
  }.reverse
```

Just replace `rs.head.endsWith("e")` with your own function.

Comment: I don't know why, but I always forget that foldLeft tracks a type that can be different from the list type. +1

Answer (score 2):

A foldLeft as @kaktusito posted is the best way. Below is the internals of how it works....for the most part.

```
def partialReduce(list : List[String]): List[String] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def internalRecurse(previousWord: String)(reducedList: List[String], finalList: List[String]): List[String] = 
    reducedList match {
      case Nil => finalList :+ previousWord //No more words, just add the previous to the list and return
      case head :: rest => {
        //if ends with e, run through the rest with the new word being the old + the head
        if(previousWord endsWith "e") internalRecurse(previousWord + " " + head)(rest, finalList)
        //if doesn't end with e, append the previous word to the final list 
        //and run the rest with the head as the next to check
        else internalRecurse(head)(rest, finalList :+ previousWord)
      }
    }

  //Call the internal method only if there is at least one item in the list
  list match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case head :: rest => internalRecurse(head)(rest, List())
  }
}
```

Also, I am going to post my pattern matching version as I like the look better:

```
val result = sen.foldLeft(List[String]()) {
    (curList, s) => {
       curList match {
         case Nil => List(s)
         case head :: rest => {
           if(head endsWith "e") head + " " + s :: rest
           else s :: curList
         }
       }
    }   
  }.reverse
```

Comment: It did work!  but I still need more time on understanding your code. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: `case Nil => List(s); case head :: rest  if head endsWith "e" => head + " " + s :: rest; case _ =>  s :: curList}` (only on multiple lines) maybe?

Comment: Yah, I was optimizing, however since it is a vanilla else then I prematurely optimized....